# dynamic creation of table and how to insert data

Tags: javascript, java

how to create a table and insert the column and row values in Oracle database which are dynamically given by the user from a JSP page and we have developed a jsp which shows add a column and add row can be incremented as per the user requirement and that same input data can be inserted in the database. can anyone please help me out this problem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <title>SB Admin - Start Bootstrap Template</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS-->
  <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
  <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!-- Page level plugin CSS-->
  <link href="vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
  <link href="css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
  #rom{
  display:none;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="fixed-nav sticky-footer bg-dark" id="page-top">
  <!-- Navigation-->
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <h2 ><p class="small" style="color:red;">Employee list</p></h2>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-sidenav" id="exampleAccordion">
        <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Dashboard">
  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="nav-link" href="employeeHome.html">
            <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            <span class="nav-link-text" style="color:#60b5ff"><b>Home</b></span>
          </a>
        </li>
  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Charts">
          <a class="nav-link" href="employeeEditProfile.html">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i>
            <span class="nav-link-text">Edit Profile</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Components">
          <a class="nav-link nav-link-collapse collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseComponents" data-parent="#exampleAccordion">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-file-text"></i>
            <span class="nav-link-text">Tickets</span>
          </a>
          <ul class="sidenav-second-level collapse" id="collapseComponents">
            <li>
              <a href="employeeAddTicket.html">Add Ticket</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="employeeEditTicket.html">Edit Ticket</a>
            </li>
   <li>
              <a href="employeeViewTicket.html">View Tickets</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Example Pages">
          <a class="nav-link nav-link-collapse collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExamplePages" data-parent="#exampleAccordion">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-wrench"></i>
            <span class="nav-link-text">Test Management</span>
          </a>
          <ul class="sidenav-second-level collapse" id="collapseExamplePages">
            <li>
                                       <a href="executivePTR.html">Prepare Test Report</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="executivePTD.html">Prepare Test Data</a>
                                </li>
                                
                                <li>
                                    <a href="executivePBR.html">Prepare Bug Report</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="executiveVTR.html"> View Test Report</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="executiveModifyTestReport.html">Modify Test Report</a>
                                </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Link">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-bell"></i>
            <span class="nav-link-text">Notifications</span>
          </a>
        </li>
  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav sidenav-toggler">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-center" id="sidenavToggler">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-left"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        
        
        
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Breadcrumbs-->
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item">
          <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Tables</li>
      </ol>
      <!-- Example DataTables Card-->
      <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="card-header">
          <i class="fa fa-table"></i> Test Data</div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="tb" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
              <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr id="myRow">
                  <th>Type of Testing</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
     <tr>
     <form>
     <td id="sel"><select class="form-control" id="sel1">
     <option select disabled>Test Result</option>
     <option>Positive</option>
     <option>Negative</option>
     </select>
     </form>
     </tr>
              <tfoot>
                <tr>
    
                  
                </tr>
              </tfoot>
              <tbody>
               
              </tbody>
            </table>
   <div align="center">
   <button onclick="addColumn('tb')" class="btn btn-info" id="addColumn">Add Column</button>
   
                  <button id="addMores" class="btn btn-info">Add Row</button>
      <div id="rom">
      <input class="form-control"  type="text" name="val" id="for" >
      </div>
      </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer small text-muted">Updated yesterday at 11:59 PM</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid-->
    <!-- /.content-wrapper-->
    
    <!-- Scroll to Top Button-->
    <a class="scroll-to-top rounded" href="#page-top">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
    </a>
    <!-- Logout Modal-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ready to Leave?</h5>
            <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">Select "Logout" below if you are ready to end your current session.</div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="login.html">Logout</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script>
function addColumn(tb)
{
 var tbHeadObj = document.getElementById(tb).tHead;
 for (var h=0; h<tbHeadObj.rows.length; h++) {
  var newTH = document.createElement('th');
  var x=document.getElementById('rom').innerHTML;
  newTH.innerHTML=x;
  tbHeadObj.rows[h].appendChild(newTH);
  
 }

 var tbBodyObj = document.getElementById(tb).tBodies[0];
 for (var i=0; i<tbBodyObj.rows.length; i++) {
  var newCell = tbBodyObj.rows[i].insertCell(-1);
  var x=document.getElementById('rom').innerHTML;
  newCell.innerHTML = x;
 }
}
function deleteColumn(tblId)
{
 var allRows = document.getElementById(tblId).rows;
 for (var i=0; i<allRows.length; i++) {
  if (allRows[i].cells.length > 1) {
   allRows[i].deleteCell(-1);
  }
 }
}</script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#addMores').on('click', function() {
              var data = $("#tb tr:eq(1)").clone(true).appendTo("#tb");
              data.find("input").val('');
     });
     $(document).on('click','.remove', function() {
         var trIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
            if(trIndex>0) {
             $(this).closest("tr").remove();
           } else {
             alert("Sorry!! Can't remove first row!");
           }
      });
}); 
   
</script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
    <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Page level plugin JavaScript-->
    <script src="vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
    <script src="js/sb-admin.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom scripts for this page-->
    <script src="js/sb-admin-datatables.min.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to step back and solve your problems step by step. There are a lot "and"s in your question. We cannot respond to all of these. You need to learn the basic steps first. Try to learn how to work with Java (or Jakarta) EE to serve static jsp pages to the client (a browser). Then use Oracle DB to create a table based on the data in the db. Then work further to make the content dynamically based on the data in db. Eventually you will figure out how to solve your problem.

Comment: Give the same name to all input controls and add a submit button, When the user submits data you can access each every parameters as an array. again iterate these arrays to save to DB.